# Evaluation of MeijerG function returns `Arguments are not consistent` error

Tags: numerics, special-functions

The following input

```
N[MeijerG[{{0}, {1}}, {{-1, 0, 0}, {}}, 1]]
```

causes Mathematica to complain that `MeijerG[{{0},{1}},{{-1,0,0},{}},1] does not exist. Arguments are not consistent`.

What is the problem and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the Meijer G-function on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function#Definition_of_the_Meijer_G-function) states that

> The definition holds under the following assumptions:
>
> - $0 ≤ m ≤ q$ and $0 ≤ n ≤ p$, where $m$, $n$, $p$ and $q$ are integer numbers,
> - $a_k − b_j ≠ 1, 2, 3,...$ for $k = 1, 2, ..., n$ and $j = 1, 2, ..., m$, which implies that no pole of any $Γ(bj − s), j = 1, 2, ..., m$, coincides with any pole of any $Γ(1 − ak + s), k = 1, 2, ..., n$
> - z ≠ 0

In particular your problem arises from the second condition.
From the mathematica [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeijerG.html) we see that $a_k$ and $b_j$, for $1 \le k \le n$ and $1 \le j \le m$, are the elements in the first and third input list, respectively.

In your case, you passed $a_1 = 0$ and $b_1=-1, b_2=0, b_3=0$.
The error is given because $a_1 - b_1 = 1$, value for which the function is not defined.

You can confirm that this is indeed the problem by simply slightly changing $b_1$, for example making it $b_1 = -1.1$, which evaluates without error and gives you the numerical output:

```
In[5]:= N@MeijerG[
  {{0}, {1}},
  {{-1.1, 0, 0}, {}},
  1
  ]

Out[5]= -11.0637 - 6.97741*10^-14 I
```

Comment: Great, thanks much!